# How to write For loop with two index value in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, for-loop

I have java code like the following:

```java
class Solution {

    public String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs) {
        // Argument checks
        if (strs == null || strs.length == 0) return "";
        if (strs.length == 1) return strs[0];
        
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Arrays.sort(strs);
        char[] first = strs[0].toCharArray();
        char[] last = strs[strs.length - 1].toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < first.length && j < last.length; i++, j++) {
            if (first[i] != last[j]) break;
            sb.append(first[i]);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

My question is how I write for loop like `for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < first.length && j < last.length; i++, j++)` in Kotlin? Thanks!

===== Update ======== 29 July 2022

I think I am providing a bad code example here... please focus on the question: how I write for loop like `for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < first.length && j < last.length; i++, j++)` in Kotlin?

Comment: i think in kotlin you should use a while-loop for such a thing.

Comment: it seems in your example you don't need two indices, you can use one index and calculate max index using min function, does my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73156100) work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Vadik's answer shows, in this particular case the indexes both take the same values, so only one is needed; that leads to a nice simplification of the code, with a neat Kotlin implementation.

However, there isn't always such a neat solution. So it's worth knowing that **any old-style `for` loop (in C or Java) can be easily converted to a `while` loop**:

```
for (<initialisers>; <condition>; <updates>) {
    // …loop body…
}
```

becomes:

```
<initialisers>;
while (<condition>) {
    // …loop body…
    <updates>;
}
```

That simple transformation can be done for *any* `for` loop, however complicated. And since Kotlin has `while`, the result translates directly into Kotlin.

A few points to be aware of:

- If the condition is blank, you'd have to substitute `true`.
- Any loop variables are now declared *outside* the loop, so their scope is larger. That brings the possibility of name clashes (if the outer scope already defines variables with those name(s) — e.g. from expanding an earlier loop), and subtle bugs. So you may need to rename them.
- Having the loop-control code split across three different places can be less concise, and harder to follow. However, that's more of an issue for simple, obvious loops, which are already well catered for in Kotlin — for the more complex ones that'd need this treatment, this may make them clearer.

Answer (score 3):

In your case both indices are the same, so you can use `min` function to calculate last index:

```
import kotlin.math.min

fun longestCommonPrefix() {
    ...
    val first: CharArray = ...
    val last: CharArray = ...
    for (i in 0 until min(first.size, last.size)) {
        if (first[i] != last[i]) break
        sb.append(first[i])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another general thing you can do is use `zip` to pair up two sequences of values - the result will be as long as the shorter sequence (i.e. only complete pairs):

```
first.indices.zip(last.indices) { (a, b) ->
    // do something with them - you actually get a Pair so you could skip the
    // deconstruction into two variables, and just refer to it.first and it.second
}
```

which isn't super useful in this case since both values are incrementing from *0*, but you can make it more general:

```
println(first.indices.zip(0 until last.size step 2))

>> [(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 6), (4, 8), (5, 10)]
```

So you can define two separate sequences of values, and make a loop that uses a value from each on every iteration, which is similar to what your `for` loop is doing. And of course it doesn't have to be indices, you could create sequences of the actual elements you want to reference too.

It's not as efficient (creates a `List` and `Iterables` under the hood), but for that you'd really need to work directly with indices in a `for` loop or with a `while` like *gidds* is suggesting. (Unless you know for sure something is compiled to an efficient form, e.g. `for (i in first.indices)` *does* compile to a basic `for` loop with no iterator.)

---

Also this probably goes against the spirit of what you're doing, but if you keep them as `String`s, you can do this:

```
first.commonPrefixWith(last)
```

Just in case you didn't know ;)